# Show WebView ViewController through the xib View

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, presentviewcontroller

I have a xib view and a button in it but when i try to configure it to present a ViewController with a WebView it shows some errors.

the xib file:

```
class popUpView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var payNowPopUp: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var priceTextFieldPopUp: UITextField!

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
}

func xibSetup(frame: CGRect){
    let view = loadXib()
    view.frame = frame
    addSubview(view)
    popUpViewInterface.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}

func loadXib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "popUpView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    return view!
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    priceTextFieldPopUp.resignFirstResponder()
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    
    priceTextFieldPopUp.resignFirstResponder()
    
    return true
}


@IBAction func payNowToWebView(_ sender: Any) {
    
    guard let mainTabBarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "paymentWebView")
    else {
        return
    }
    
    mainTabBarController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    self.present(mainTabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Inside the `@IBAction func payNowToWebView(_ sender: Any) { }` I want to present a viewController when the button is clicked but it's showing some errors like: `Value of type 'popUpView' has no member 'storyboard'` and `Value of type 'popUpView' has no member 'present'`

Answer (score 0):

`present` is a method  and `storyboard` is a property both of them inside a `UIViewController` instance not a `UIView` instance

You can replace `self.storyboard` with `UIStoryboard(name:"YourName",nil)`but for `present` you need a vc to show the needed one from it most commonly to have a delegate weak variable inside that view that references the vc where the view is inside or you may get the app's window root vc then `vc.present(.....`

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this (Remember to replace 'Main' with your storyboard name):

```
@IBAction func payNowToWebView()  {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: paymentWebView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("paymentWebView") as! PaymentWebView
        let currentController = self.getRootVC()
        currentController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }

func getRootVC() -> UIViewController? {

    if let rootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        var currentController: UIViewController! = rootController
        while( currentController.presentedViewController != nil ) {
            currentController = currentController.presentedViewController
        }
        return currentController
    }
    return nil

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate i tried it and when i type the identifier and run it it gives an error like this, "Could not find a storyboard named 'paymentWebView' in bundle NSBundle , But the name is correct and its excactly like all other VC i made

Comment: Are you sure your storyboard name is 'paymentWebView' because it seems like a View Controller name. Just make sure your replace 'Main' with your storyboard file name and 'paymentWebView' with the ViewController name

Comment: Yes man I triple checked the name and tried different names and all but still there is something wrong its showing this error , Could not find a storyboard named 'paymentWebsiteView' in bundle NSBundle </Users/comuter/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6A9B32-0E-47B-30-ACFC941/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/86403862-E6B8-42DD-AAF0-3009123350/iOS.app> (loaded)"